# Protocol buffers with no optional fields: Fixed size?

Tags: networking, protocol-buffers

I'm using Google Protocol buffers and am trying to determine the following:

If my protocol buffer contains no repeating fields, and all fields are required, is it safe to assume the buffer will *always* be the same size, regardless of its contents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No. This is not correct assumption** given the information provided.

[Some types (notably Base 128 Varints) use a variable-encoding](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html). Also consider Strings (with unspecified payloads) as another counter-example.

Happy coding.